# jmeter double Loop - inner loop works only once

Tags: java, loops, jmeter

I have a Test Plan like below:

```
Test Plan
  SQL 1
     Save to file A
     Outer While loop
        CSV= file A
        SQL 2 => many rows
            Save to file B
            Inner While loop   <--- executes only once
               CSV = file B, recycle at EOF = false, stop thread at EOF = false
                   JSR223 sampler
```

My Inner While loop reads all the lines and ends when reaches EOF.
Then control goes back to Outer WHILE loop, executes the SQL 2, but when comes back to Inner loop, counter is set to EOF and hence never executes the INNER Loop's samplers.
What can I do to use the Inner Loop many times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not seeing your While Controller's condition and associated [JMeter Functions or Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) names and values it is hard to say exactly what's going on, my expectation is that the While Controller's condition becomes `false` somewhere in the Outer Loop and you don't reset it to `true` in the Outer Loop.

Something like:

- Outer While Loop

  - Set `A` variable to `true`
  - do something else

    - Inner Loop (condition `"${A}" == "true"`

      - do something which sets `A` to `false`

You can inspect JMeter Variables values at any stage of the test using [Debug Sample](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination, see [How to Debug your Apache JMeter Script](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) article to learn more about JMeter tests troubleshooting techniques.